# How to know that single engine aeroplanes are not allowed to depart on the TETAN SID?

Tags: icao, sid-star, departure-sid, south-africa

I'm studying for my IR exam and came across another tricky AIP question.

> Which of the following statements about the TETAN 1A standard departure chart are correct?
>
> 1. **Single engine aeroplanes are not allowed to depart on this SID** >>> marked as correct
> 2. Aircraft equipped only with RNAV (GNSS) avionics equipment may not fly this procedure
> 3. If the SID is in force, an aircraft that cannot comply with the minimum climb gradient on the chart may not take off
> 4. The altitude at which Cape Town Radar control must be cancelled will not be confirmed in the ATC departure clearance

I would say #3 seems more likely because of the terrain. However, it says that that if an aircraft cannot comply with the climb gradient, it just needs to notify ATC.

As for #1... how would one determine that? I've had a look at the TETAN C and TETAN B Dep charts and they don't indicate anything about being single engine or multi engine aircraft limited either.

I'm located in South Africa and we use ICAO as a reference for most of our regulations.

[image]
(Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgSKU.png) or on image to view full size, or [here](http://www.caa.co.za/Aeronautical%20Charts/Cape%20Town%20INTL%20-%20FACT/FACT_TETAN%201A%20RWY%2019_DEP-05_.pdf) for the PDF)

Comment: Well it can't be 3 because it just says if you can't comply, contact ATC, not that you can't depart.  You just can't accept the SID in your clearance.  As to why there is a single engine ban, I'm a bit stumped; does that mean you can't depart in a single engine turboprop?  Did you look around the set of charts for some other comments or restrictions?

Comment: Your link throws a 500 for me

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Just as a general comment, if you ask "is X allowed?" then you're most likely asking about regulations. If so, please always tell us the specific country or regulations that you're asking about. That helps the community to give you better answers.

Comment: As I read the question, I don't understand why you have "1... >>> Correct". Is this a typo? Are you trying to imply that 1 is correct?

ATC is allowed to relax constraints in a SID that are due to traffic/airspace, but it is not allowed to relax terrain restrictions. It can, however, reroute you to avoid terrain.

Comment: @MarkJonesJr. I have no. 1 marked as correct according to the material that we've been supplied with to prepare for the exam. It is the most correct answer according to the CAA. I do agree with what you are saying but they mark it as incorrect if you choose this answer no. 3 in the exam.

Comment: I don't really know, but the only reason I can imagine is that the climb gradient due to terrain implies—by some general rule—climb gradient with one engine inoperative, which would then single-engine aircraft obviously not satisfy. Can you try looking for something like that in the general materials?

Comment: As a complete guess, is there a regulation that means that single-engine aircraft may not be routed over water by ATC? The climb rate is certainly achievable in many single-engine aircraft so I don't know why that would be a consideration.

Comment: @Skydemon, is there also a text part of the AIP for this SID? I am asking because in a lot of AIPs I came across this contains the RNAV coding and other details/restrictions.

Comment: In the USA test preparation products use questions from the FAA but the answer set is created by the publishing company because the FAA does not make the official test answer key public. So it is not uncommon to find answers sets in preparation products that are poorly worded or just not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a specific note on the TETAN SID chart limiting this procedure to multi-engine airplanes, I think the marked answer of #1 is incorrect. I think number #3 is correct. If you can't meet the climb gradient restriction you should not take off (single-engine or multi-engine).

The **6.2%** climb gradient **restriction** shown on the bottom of the SID procedure is meant to be calculated and determined **prior to departure**. If you have calculated/determined that your aircraft cannot meet that minimum climb gradient **you cannot takeoff**.

If you are assigned this SID in your IFR clearance received prior to takeoff then you should notify ATC (as it states in the NOTE on the chart) that you cannot comply with its climb gradient restriction and then anticipate receiving an alternative departure procedure.

As answer #3 above in the OP's question states:

> If the SID is in force, an aircraft that cannot comply with the minimum climb gradient on the chart **may not take off.**

Once you are airborne (perhaps IMC and at night) is not the time to be asking ATC for an alternate procedure (to avoid the terrain).

(*The school-solution answer of #1 could just be an error in the test construction.  There are numerous high performance single-engine airplanes that would be able to meet the 6.2% climb gradient to 8500 feet*)